# Issue in calling a function by different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, webclient

I have a function. I want to call this function several times by different threads. How can I do that ?. My function is below

```
public void DownloadImage(List<String> imageUrl)
    {
        imageCount = imageUrl.Count;

        foreach (string url in imageUrl)
        {
            StartDownload(url);
        }
    }
```

I have 10 images to download. I am using webclient to download images. So I want to call this function by 10 threads. How can I do that ?

I tried the below code. But it showing compile error

```
ParameterizedThreadStart starter;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            _imageDownloader = new ImageDownloader(); //this is class where I defined the function above ie DownloadImage
            _imageDownloader.OnCompleted+=new Completed(_imageDownloader_OnCompleted);
            starter = new ParameterizedThreadStart(_imageDownloader.DownloadImage); // in this line it showing a compile error "No overload for 'DownloadImage' matches delegate 'System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart'"
            Thread imageThread = new Thread(starter);
            imageThread.Start();
        }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Task Parallel Library:

```
public void DownloadImage(List<String> imageUrl)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(imageUrl, url => StartDownload(url));
}
```